# Calculate the numbers of a geometric sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, geometric-series

The sum of $3$ numbers in a geometric sequence is $175.5$:

$$b_1 + b_2 + b_3 = 175.5$$

And the product of the same numbers is $91125$:

$$b_1 \cdot b_2 \cdot b_3 = 91125$$

I used the formula for the product and calculated $b_2$ which equals to $45$, but when I try to calculate the other terms I get stuck with this formula and I am not sure if the formula I get is correct:

$$45q^2 - 130.5q + 45 = 0$$

Thanks in advance

Comment: your quadratic looks fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let the three numbers be $\frac ar, a, ar$.

Product:
$$\frac ar\cdot a\cdot ar=91125\\
a^3=91125\\
a=45$$

Sum: 
$$45 (\frac 1r+1+r)=175.5\\
r^2-2.9r+1=0\\
(r-2.5)(r-0.4)=0\\
r=0.4, 2.5$$

Hence the numbers are either $$18,45,112.5$$ or $$112.5,45.18$$.

Comment: How did you convert this equation r^2−2.9r+1=0 to (r-2.5)(r-0.4)=0?

Comment: You might be more familiar with quadratics with integer coefficients. Multiply the equation by $10$, resulting in $10r^2-29r+10=0$ which then factorises to $(2r-5)(5r-2)=0$ giving the same answers as before.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

Comment: You're welcome. Hope it was helpful.